# -[NSManagedObject faultingState] returns 0 even when the object is being materialised from a fault

Tags: cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing

I am using the faultingState property of a managedObject to find out if the object is in transitional state while receiving KVO notifcations.

```
NFSDealer *dealer = user.dealers[0];
Asset *asset = finance.asset;
```

The object under discussion is finance which is a fault. When I acess the asset property the fault is triggered and finance is initialized. During this process i receive KVO change notifications for finance. But the faultingState of finance is returning 0 in those notifications. Is this the correct behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the observation code. I am using FBKVOController with custom actions.

```
- (void)didChangeDepositAmount:(NSDictionary *)change object:(Finance *)observedObject{

if (observedObject.faultingState != 0) {

    return;

}

if ([change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] doubleValue] == [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] doubleValue]) {

    return; // a hack around the faultingState :(

}

double newValue = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] doubleValue];

_depositDataSource.object = @(newValue);}
```

Furthermore if i turn the object into fault i still get these notifications but the faultingState returns 2 during these notification that makes sense. But again when the fault is realized faultingStatus returns 0 in the notifications. Here is the code

```
[finance.managedObjectContext refreshObject:finance mergeChanges:NO];
Asset *faultedAsset = finance.asset;
```

Here is the documentation for faultingState

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger faultingState
```

> 0 if the object is fully initialized as a managed object and not transitioning to or from another state, otherwise some other value. This property allows you to determine if an object is in a transitional phase when receiving a key-value observing change notification.

Any idea about to figure out if the notification are triggered due to a fault being materialised into an initialised object?